# Проверить сделал ли пользователь репост Callback API VK

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Как можно при помощи Callback API VK, проверить сделал ли пользователь который написал в сообщения сообщества репост? Без ключа пользователя и сервисного естественно, есть только ключ сообщества. Такое реализовать точно можно, видел много примеров.

**wall.getReposts** - не подходит, так как максимум можно получить 1000 репостов, а как проверять, если их около 100 тысяч? ну и он требует сервисного ключа, которого нет у сообщества

Answer (score 0):

Это придётся делать перебором.
Как это реализовать на php я не знаю, но могу подсказать алгоритм, а как его на конкретном языке написать, я думаю, не трудно разобраться.
Реализовать это можно примерно так:

Берёте нужное количество записей со стены пользователя следующим образом:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=id_юзера&count=нужное_количество&filter=owner&access_token=ключ_доступа&v=5.67
```

В ответ вам придёт примерно следующий JSON:

```
{
  "response": {
    "count": нужное_количество,
    "items": [
      {
        "id": id_записи_на_стене_юзера,
        "from_id": id_юзера,
        "owner_id": id_юзера,
        ...
        "copy_history": [
          {
            "id": id_записи_со_стены_сообщества, 
            "owner_id": -id_группы,
            ...
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Если в записи имеется репост со стены, там будет объект `copy_history`.
Так вот, чтобы проверить, сделал ли пользователь репост записи `https://vk.com/wall-idгруппы_idзаписи`, нужно пробежаться по каждой записи из этого ответа (по всем JSONObject'ам в массиве "items"), и проверить, совпадает ли `wall`+`id_группы`+`_`+`id_записи` с нужной вам записью, и если да - значит среди последних `нужное_количество` записей на стене пользователя есть репост нужной вам записи.